# Using EWS to remove room from a meeting

Tags: soap, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I need to remove a room from specific meeting using EWS (SOAP).
I have an impersonation user and using it, im manage to get a list of all the meetings in a specific room, but I wan't manage so fur to update the meeting by removing the room from it  (make the room available for booking).
I tried to remove all attendees from the meeting, it removes the attendees but keeps the room, I tried to remove location - it clears the location field but still keeps the room as meeting attendee.
Help would be appreciated, near to give up here :(

Answer (score 0):

OK, just solved it:)
The answer was to impersonate a room account and then simple decline the invitation.
hope it will help to someone...